# Modular arithmetic , calculate $54^{2013}\pmod{280}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

> How do you calculate: $54^{2013}\pmod{280}$?

I'm stuck because $\gcd(54,280)$ is not $1$. Thanks.

Comment: HINT: Use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: OK thanks , I will try

Comment: See also: [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$54^{2013}=27^{2013}\cdot2^{2013}=3^{6039}\cdot 2^{2013}$$

Now $3^{6039}$ is not a problem modulo $280$, and you should not have much difficulty reducing $2^{2013}$ even by hand - starting e.g. $2^8=256\equiv -24$, then $2^{16}\equiv (-24)^2=576\equiv 16$

Comment: Yes this is a good method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$280=2^3\cdot 5\cdot 7$. As usual, the following Chinese Remainder Theorem algorithm is straightforward. Here we didn't need Euler's Theorem, but it is often useful.

Clearly $54^{2013}=8k$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. Then $$54^{2013}\equiv (-1)^{2013}\equiv -1\equiv -6\equiv 8k\equiv 3k\pmod{\!5}$$

$$\stackrel{:3}\iff k\equiv -2\equiv 3\pmod{\! 5}\iff k=5m+3$$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z$. Then $54^{2013}=8k=8(5m+3)=40m+24$.

$$54^{2013}\equiv (-2)^{2013}\equiv -(2^3)^{671}\equiv -(1)^{671}\equiv -1\pmod{\! 7}$$

$$\iff -1\equiv 40m+24\equiv -2m+3\iff -2m\equiv -4\stackrel{:(-2)}\iff m\equiv 2\pmod{\! 7}$$

$\iff m=7a+2$ for some $a\in\Bbb Z$. Then $54^{2013}=40(7a+2)+24=280a+104$.

Comment: Ok I understand it, Nice method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As $280=2^3\cdot5\cdot7$

let us start with $54^{2013-3}\pmod{\dfrac{280}{2^3}}$ i.e., $54^{2010}\pmod{35}$

Now $54\equiv-1\pmod5\implies54^2\equiv(-1)^2\equiv1$

and $54\equiv-2\pmod7\implies54^3\equiv(-2)^3\equiv-1,54^6\equiv(-1)^2\equiv1$

$\implies54^6\equiv1\pmod{35}$

As $2010\equiv0\pmod6,54^{2010}\equiv54^0\pmod{35}\equiv1$

As $a\equiv b\pmod m\implies a\cdot c\equiv b\cdot c\pmod{m\cdot c}\ \ \ \ (1)$

$54^{2010}\cdot54^3\equiv1\cdot54^3\pmod{35\cdot54^3}$

As $280|35\cdot54^3,54^{2010+3}\equiv54^3\pmod{280}$

Again as $54=2\cdot3^3,54^3=\cdots=2^33^9$

and $3^3\equiv-8\pmod{35},8=2^3;3^9\equiv-(2^3)^3\equiv-2^9$

Now $2^7\equiv-12\pmod{35}\implies2^9\equiv-12\cdot2^2\equiv-13$

$\implies3^9\equiv13\pmod{35}$

Using $(1),54^3=2^3\cdot3^9\equiv2^3\cdot13\pmod{2^3\cdot35}\equiv104$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use quick exponentiation (also known as exponentiation by squaring), which is a very common and useful but, in this specific case, a bit brute method. Take the binary expansion of the exponent $2013=2^{10}+2^9+2^8+2^7+2^6+2^4+2^3+2^2+2^0$ and then do repeated squaring of $54$ to get $54^1,54^2,54^{2^2},\dots,54^{2^{10}}$. In every step you can take the least positive number in the residue class so normally it gives you relatively small numbers to deal with.

If you need more details, let me know.

Comment: Ok thank you, i understand it. But it is maybe a bit long. I will trie it.

Comment: Yes, in this specific case it is bit long. But it can be easily programmed in most of the programming languages and is widely used in mathematics or applications of mathematics. So it was more of a general answer than idea for solving this particular situation.

Comment: Ok yes, I will remember it, in other exercices this method is maybe also useful.